# Data Testing in EmberJS and QUnit using fixtures

Tags: testing, ember.js, qunit

I have a simple ember application and I want to test it, without making server for API calls.

I've looked around a bunch and found this piece of code which helps tremendously.  Problem is for testing I want to use the fixture adapter (makes sense, right?)

```
 @store = Lfg.__container__.lookup('store:main')
```

Here is my model:

```
Lfg.Activity = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  people: DS.attr('number')
  maxPeople: DS.attr('number')
  host: DS.attr('string')
```

Then inside an `Em.run =>` I do this

```
  Lfg.reset()

  container = new Ember.Container()
  # These are my models... just one for now.
  [
    'activity'
  ].forEach (x,i) ->
    container.register 'model:'+x, Lfg.get( Ember.String.classify(x) )
  # It's essentially just: container.register("model:activity", Lfg.Activity)


  @store = DS.Store.create
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.extend()
    container: container
```

But I keep getting errors with the serializer.  I tried adding the serializer but doesn't help.  Do I need to `container.register` other things as well?

The error I get is `TypeError: Cannot call method 'serialize' of undefined` coming from mockJSON method, more specifically `store.serializerFor(type)` is returning null.

If I set store via `store = Lfg.__container__.lookup('store:main')` and then `store.serializerFor(Lfg.Activity)` it seems to work ok in the console -- is this not the same store?  I want to use the one with the fixture adapter.  I tried setting the serializer but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using something like mockjax to mock the api endpoints, then using qunit and the built in helpers provided by Ember and qunit

Here's an example of how to set up a simple json response

```
$.mockjax({
    url:  '/colors',
    dataType: 'json',
  responseText: {
    colors:[
      {
        id: 1,
        color: "red"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        color: "green"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        color: "blue"
      }
     ]
  }
});
```

And a test that would hit this endpoint

```
test("root lists 3 colors", function(){
  var store = App.__container__.lookup('store:main');
  var colors = store.find('color');
  stop();
  colors.then(function(arr){
    start();
    equal(arr.get('length'), 3, 'store returns 3 records');
  });      
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wipo/3/edit

Comment: is it not possible to test EmberJS with fixture data?

Comment: Emberjs or ember data, they are two different products

Comment: I'm using both, and trying to test with qunit. It seems we are running into the same issues as OP. The EmberJS docs are not very clear on how to do this.